# gitlab pages : special webroot for certbot challenges

Tags: gitlab, lets-encrypt, gitlab-pages

I'm trying to tweak GitLab Pages (10.8.2) with the objective to have its Pages domain (example.io) TLS enabled with Let's Encrypt.

I have a working Pages setup on regular HTTP with :

```
pages_external_url "http://example.io"
```

The ideas I found on Google is to provide the following to serve the certbot challenges:

```
pages_nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "location ^~ /.well-known { root /var/www/letsencrypt; }"
```

Then issuing `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Then I create a test file at `/var/www/letsencrypt/bla` and try to access it with a browser at http://example.io/.well-known/bla with no success : I get a `301` and redirected to the main GitLab domain at https://example.ltd/.well-known/bla (the main GitLab is already TLS enabled).

What do I miss here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [as stated about ACME](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-and-wildcard-certificate-support-is-live/55579)

> wildcard domains must be validated using the DNS-01 challenge type

so trying to setup a webroot for `*.example.io` challenges is useless.

Second, with the Nginx setup above, the file is rather expected at `/var/www/letsencrypt/.well-known/bla`